# What is wrong with my code? I can't print the result list

Tags: c#, list

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1,1,2};
List<int> list1= new List<int>() {  1, 2 };
List<int> list2 = (list.Except(list1)).ToList();
foreach(int item in list2)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

I want to print elements of list1 except list2

What I mean is since 1,2 is common in both the lists so those should be removed and I should get a new list with only { 1 }.

Please help

Comment: _"I want to print elements of `list1` except `list2`"_ - okay, but your code has `list.Except(list1)` - which is not `list1.Except(list2)` - is your eyesight okay?

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: When you use `list.Except(list1)` it removes ALL elements from `list` that also exist in `list1`. That means it will remove BOTH instances of `1` and the single instance of `2`, resulting in an empty sequence.

Comment: What elements are you expecting to be in `list2` and why?

Comment: @MatthewWatson `Except` is a Linq method, not a `List<T>` - All Linq `Enumerable` extension-methods treat `source` as read-only: it won't "remove" anything from `list`.

Comment: It returns an empty collection.

Comment: @Dai Yes, I just meant that the result would be an empty sequence

Comment: Have you checked out my answer?

Answer (score 3):

[`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-7.0) as docs say is :

> **The set difference** of two sets is defined as the members of the first set that don't appear in the second set.
> This method returns those elements in first that don't appear in second. It doesn't return those elements in second that don't appear in first. Only unique elements are returned.

So the result will not include any element from first which are present in the second one not considering the counts. So `list2` will be effectively empty.

Assuming you want take in account counts of elements in both you will need to use some other approach. For example build a dictionary where number will be the key and value will be corresponding count and then iterate the second list and reduce counts for corresponding keys. And then take all the keys where count is greater than 0.